# Flutter how to get total items in all lists

Tags: flutter, dart

I got this list in flutter:

```
List<dynamic> days = [];
```

Printing it gives me this result:

```
[[1, 3, 4, 6], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Now I want to get total items in this list.
What is the best way to do that?

I have tried this but it doesn't work:

```
print(days.sum);
```

I want to get the total items from all lists.
(1,3,4,6 + 1,2,3)= total:7items.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    List<dynamic> days = [[1, 3, 4, 6], [1, 2, 3]];
int length = 0 ;
for (var item in days ){
length = length + int.parse ('${ item.length ?? 0}');
} 
print ('Total Length : $length  ');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void main() {
  List<dynamic> list = [1, 2, [3, 4, [5, 6]], 7, 8];
  int count = countElements(list);
  print(count); 
}    

int countElements(List<dynamic> list) {
  int count = 0;
  for (var element in list) {
    if (element is List) {
      count += countElements(element);
    } else {
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

Here is a recursive function. This example prints "8".

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you are using `List<dynamic>` as the type of `days` you can write

```
print(days.whereType<List>().flattened.length);
```

If `days` was declared as `List<List>` to begin with like

```
List<List> days = [];
```

you can shorten it to

```
print(days.flattened.length);
```

flattened is part of the `collection` package so you would need to add that and import it like:

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';
```

If you do not wish to use that package you could copy the implementation of it yourself and add it to your code:

```
/// Extensions on iterables whose elements are also iterables.
extension IterableIterableExtension<T> on Iterable<Iterable<T>> {
  /// The sequential elements of each iterable in this iterable.
  ///
  /// Iterates the elements of this iterable.
  /// For each one, which is itself an iterable,
  /// all the elements of that are emitted
  /// on the returned iterable, before moving on to the next element.
  Iterable<T> get flattened sync* {
    for (var elements in this) {
      yield* elements;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It gives me error: The getter 'flattened' isn't defined for the type 'Iterable<List<dynamic>>'.
Try importing the library that defines 'flattened', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'flattened'.

Comment: @MatKoffman I clarified the answer by saying it's part of a package

Comment: this gives me the correct result: print(days.whereType<List>().flattened.length);

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use fold method.

```
List<dynamic> days = [1, 2, 3, 4 , 6];
  
  var sumDays = days.fold<dynamic>(0, (prev, element) => prev + element);
  
  print(sumDays);
```

in print it returns 16.

Comment: I just want the length of all lists in days. It should return 7 instead of 16

Comment: @MatKoffman oh, I see, my bad  `List<List<int>> days = [[1, 2, 3], [4 , 6]];
  
  int total = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < days.length; i++){
    total += days[i].length;
  }
  
  print(total);` you should indicate that your array is List<int> in other case you have to cast value to num https://dartpad.dev/?